# google mock EXPECT_CALL return value

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have the following code in C want to be test in using google testing framework:

```
a.h

void getValue(int age, int * value);

a.c

#include <a.h>

void getValue(int age, int * value)
{
   value[0] = 0;
   value[1] = 1;
}

b.c

#include <a.h>

void formValue()
{
   int value[2];
   getValue(age, value);

   /* the code to handle the value[] array */
   /* for() */
}
```

I want to test the function `void formValue()` in file `b`, so I created the following mock for `void getValue(int age, int * value)`:
    // AFileMock.hh
    #include 
    #include "a.h"

```
class AFileMock {
  public:
    AFileMock();
    ~AFileMock();
    MOCK_METHOD1(getValue, void(int, int *));
};
```

then in the test file I want to call the mocked function `getValue` and return the value for the `void getValue(int age, int * value)` part, but how to return the out coming parameter of `value array` when call a mock function?

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include <b.h>
#include <AFileMock.h>

using testing::_;
using testing::Return;
using testing::InSequence;

class BTest: public testing::Test {

protected:
   AFileMock aFile;

public:
   void SetUp() { }
   void TearDown() { }
};


TEST_F(BTest, test1)
{
   InSequence sequence;
   EXPECT_CALL(aFile, getValue(_, _)).
      Times(1); // when this mock function is called, how to return the value of the array?

   formValue();
}
```

so in this case, when the mock function is called, how to return the value of array?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot understand your sample code, `a.c` doesn't even compile. But I guess the answer you are looking for is Gmock [Actions](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies#Actions:_What_Should_It_Do?). A [rich set](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Actions) of them is provided.